# python debug: replace string between two unknown substrings

Tags: python, replace

this is my python script below, I try to use `sub()` to replace all the values between `<StartNum>` and `</StartNum>` by using a variable continous number `n` Then, write the results to a new text file.
any people could point out the mistake?

```
import re
f1 = open('name.xml', 'r')
f2 = open('result.txt', 'w')
data=f1.read()
n=5000
for line in f1:
      f2.write(re.sub('<StartNum>(.*)</StartNum>', r'<StartNum>%s</StartNum>' % str(n), data))
      if "<StartNum>" in line:
          n=n+1
f1.close() 
f2.close()
```

Comment: once you call `read` and get `data` ... you are at the end of `f1` ... you can use `f1.seek(0)` to go back to begining

Comment: What does your input look like, the file name.xml?  And what does your desired output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code.

1. You are reading the file, f1, into data but you are continuing to us f1 for the loop.  Once you have read the data, you can close the file.
2. You would probably want to split the lines up.  You can do this a number of ways.  The `readlines` method is probably the most straight forward.
3. When you are evaluating a regex in a loop, it can be very slow because it has to be recompiled each iteration.  Instead, you can compile the regex ahead of time and use it instead.
4. In your `re.sub`, you were using `data` as the source, while you actually want the line.

There are other things you could do to improve the code, but the ones listed above are pretty necessary.

I am guessing this will likely do what you want.

```
import re
f1 = open('name.xml', 'r')
f2 = open('result.txt', 'w')
data = f1.readlines()
f1.close()
n = 5000
rex = re.compile('<StartNum>(.*)</StartNum>')
for line in data:
    f2.write(rex.sub(r'<StartNum>%s</StartNum>' % str(n), line))
    if "<StartNum>" in line:
        n += 1
f2.close()
```

Given names.xml of

```
<root>
    <StartNum>1</StartNum>
    <StartNum>5</StartNum>
    <StartNum>8</StartNum>
    <StartNum>9</StartNum>
    <StartNum>13</StartNum>
    <StartNum>33</StartNum>
    <foo>
        <bar baz="5" />
    </foo>
</root>
```

result.txt will be:

```
<root>
    <StartNum>5000</StartNum>
    <StartNum>5001</StartNum>
    <StartNum>5002</StartNum>
    <StartNum>5003</StartNum>
    <StartNum>5004</StartNum>
    <StartNum>5005</StartNum>
    <foo>
        <bar baz="5" />
    </foo>
</root>
```

Comment: on a side note you should use an xml or html parser instead of regex for these things...(although in this specific instance regex should work decently)